How to deploy a Blazor WASM custom element and call it from an spa application
I have created a custom element with blazor and I need to call it from another page, but I need to have this blazor custom element on a diferent domain, the problem is when I try to call it from another domain, It doesn't load, It only runs when I manually copy de _framework and _content folders into the proyect that I want to insert the blazor custom element.
I have already tried to deploy the blazor app on static page services as netlify and when I call like this:
<script src="urlexample/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script src="urlexample/_framework/dotnet.js"></script>
<script src="urlexample/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CustomElements/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CustomElements.lib.module.js"></script>
<link rel="urlexample/stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<img src="urlexample/img/01fondo.png" alt="Background Image" />
<script src="urlexample/appsettings.json"></script> 


Well never seen a similar usage or document about this.

Use Razor components in JavaScript apps and SPA frameworks
